# Possible to restrict SVN account to read log entries only, no source code?

Tags: svn

Using SVN <strike>with svnserve</strike>, is it possible to restrict an account to viewing log entries only?

This is useful for integrating with e.g. stats publishing tools that rely on log history, without giving those tools access to all the repo source code.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible at this time.

In fact Subversion will restrict what is returned for a log request based on the path based access control for the files the revision changed (mod_authz_svn for httpd and built into svnserve when authz-db is configured).

1. If all files can be read then:

   - Server returns all details of the revision.
2. If only some of the files can be read then:

   - Server only returns the svn:author and svn:date revision properties and if -v is being used the paths of the changed paths that the requester has access to.
3. If none of the files can be read then:

   - Server doesn't even mention the revision in the log results.

With HTTPD you ought to be able to restrict the methods that the client could use and turn off bulk updates (SVNAllowBulkUpdates).  With bulk updates off they wouldn't be able to access the contents of the file as long as they can't do a GET.  However, due to other internal issues with the way mod_dav_svn is implemented this isn't possible.  svnserve doesn't have any sort of hooks to support anything like this.

This is the type of thing that will require changes on the Subversion side to be possible.

Comment: Thanks! We have an authz file so I'm sort of assuming we're using svnserve, but perhaps not?

Comment: Both httpd and svnserve can use authz files.  You can tell the difference by the protocol you're using.  If you're using svnserve you'll be using svn:// or svn+ssh:// URLs.  If you're using httpd you'll have http:// or https:// URLs.  You can do an `svn info | grep URL` to find out which you're using if you don't recall.

Comment: Ha! We're using https :) Sorry - I've updated the question accordingly. More info about how to restrict methods using httpd would be much appreciated. Can't see this in e.g, docs for mod_authz_svn.

Comment: You should be able to limit httpd by just limiting the user to the OPTIONS and REPORT request methods (Limit/LimitExcept directives) and by disabling bulk updates.  I'm about to run out to do something tonight.  I'll try to come up with a working config later this weekend and update my answer.

Comment: I've tried to get what I described above working but haven't had much luck.  Configuring httpd with this degree of restriction is a huge pain in the butt.

Comment: Updated above to note that it can't be done.  REPORT requests end up doing internal GET requests in order to check permissions.  Due to the above explanation if you restricted GET then you'd no log output.  Sorry, it was a nice idea.